# Match number within list of different length vectors

Tags: r, list, match

I want to match a number within a list containing vector of different lengths. Still my solution (below) doesn't match anything beyond the first item of each vector.

```
seq_ <- seq(1:10)
list_ <- list(seq_[1:3], seq_[4:7], seq_[8:10])
list_ 
#  [[1]]
#  [1] 1 2 3
# 
#  [[2]]
#  [1] 4 5 6 7
# 
# [[3]]
#  [1]  8  9 10
```

but

```
for (i in seq_) {
  print(match(i,list_))
}
# [1] 1
# [1] NA
# [1] NA
# [1] 3
# [1] NA
# [1] NA
# [1] NA
# [1] NA
# [1] NA
# [1] NA
```

Comment: What is `t0`? What output would you like to obtain? Please, give us an example..

Comment: If for every `i` you want a list (not a vector as there can potentially be more than 1) of its locations in `list_` then what you want is: `lapply(seq_, function(i) lapply(list_, function(elems) match(i, elems)))`. The point is: you need a nested loop, you cannot match to a list. If you need anything else, then please try to formulate it clearly.

Comment: @gagolews Sorry, I reedited the code.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, you probably will be happier with `which`, as in

EDIT:  rewrote to show the full looping over values.

```
seq_ <- seq(1:10)
list_ <- list(seq_[1:3], seq_[4:7], seq_[8:10])
matchlist<-list(length=length(list_))
    for( j in 1:length(list_)) {
       matchlist[[j]] <-  unlist(sapply(seq_, function(k) which(list_[[j]]==k) ))
    }
```

That will return the locations of all matches.  It's probably more clear what's happening if you create an input like `my.list <- list(sample(1:10,4,replace=TRUE), sample(1:10,7,replace=TRUE))`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. You also forgot a bracket.